# get id of a form field in python cgi

Tags: python, cgi

I was Programming CGI With Python and found that CGI passes information to Python in the form of a class called FieldStorage. The main attribute of class FieldStorage which i came across is 'getvalue' to get data from form fields. Is it possible to get the id value of the field?

Edit

I was wondering if i can get some unique info about the form sending data. This is because, i have a form and 2 scripts.I the form, i put item details then a script1 takes that data and saves it in the db. i have another script2 which queries a saved item data, creates a form and populates the form with the data to enable editing the item and after the user edits, the data is updated back to the db.

The updated back to the db is where the problem is. i wanted to use script 1 to do the update but in this case i wont do INSERT INTO ... i will do UPDATE Table1... Now, how do i know which request is for editing or updating. am doing this because im in a situation where the form has 70 fields and creating another script will just be copying script1 with addition of the update logic.
This is what i wanted to do with the script

script1.py

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import cgi
import cgitb; cgitb.enable()     # for troubleshooting
import MySQLdb

form = cgi.FieldStorage()

#there are 70 fields
id = form.getfirst("id");
error = form.getfirst("error");
comment = form.getfirst("comment");
product_name = form.getfirst("product_name");
verified_product_name = form.getfirst("verified_product_name");
url = form.getfirst("url");
verified_url= form.getfirst("verified_url");
.
.
.
source = form.getfirst("source");

print 'Content-type: text/html\r\n\r'
print '<html>'
print 'Update Successfull ! !'
print '</html>'


db = MySQLdb.connect(host="localhost", user="root", passwd="", db="products")


cursor = db.cursor()
sql=""

### Check the request---How do i do this?

if update: ##if the request is for updating

sql = """UPDATE item SET (id=id, error=error, comment=comment, product_name=product_name, verified_product_name=verified_product_name, url=url, verified_url=verified_url, image_url=image_url,..., source=source)"""

else: ##if the request is for inserting

sql = """INSERT INTO item (id, error, comment, product_name, verified_product_name, url, verified_url, image_url, verified_image_url, brand, verified_brand, type, verified_type, price, min_price, max_price, verified_price,..., source) VALUES ('%s', '%s', "%s", '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s',..., '%s')""" %(id, error, comment, product_name, verified_product_name, url, verified_url, image_url, verified_image_url, brand,..., source)

try:
  cursor.execute(sql,(id, error, comment, product_name, verified_product_name, url, verified_url, image_url, verified_image_url, brand, verified_brand, type, verified_type, price, min_price, max_price, verified_price, measure_unit, ..., source))

   db.commit()
except Exception as err:


   db.rollback()

   db.autocommit(True)
cursor.execute(sql)
cursor.fetchall()
db.close()
```

Hope you got the my issue. Can i do this without creating another script to do the update seperately?

Comment: the information you need is not even posted to your script, and lives in HTML

Comment: Not really sure what you're trying to get at. In terms of getting the id of the fields from the form, if they submit you can use form = cgi.FieldStorage() and then form.keys() to get all the ids of the form used and form[key].value for the value of that field in the form. But again not really sure what you're asking for the rest of your question.